# Custom component not overriding base properties

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've implemented the following library:

[React Native Material Textfield](https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-textfield)

As we know, the library has default values so instead of defining for each input:

- tintColor
- baseColor
- fontSize
- ...

I've definend my custom component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { TextField } from 'react-native-materialui-textfield';


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    inputEditText: {
        paddingVertical: 6,
    },
});

export const InputEditText = () => (
    <View style={styles.inputEditText}>
        <TextField
            label='test'
            autoCapitalize='none'
            fontSize={20}
            lineWidth={1}
            titleFontSize={16}
            labelHeight={42}
            textColor='white'
            tintColor='white'
            baseColor='rgb(225, 231, 228)'
            autoCorrect={false}
            enablesReturnKeyAutomatically={true}
            onFocus={this.onFocus}
            returnKeyType='next'
        />
    </View>
);
```

So now If I want to implement the library with my own style I've just defined:

```
<InputEditText
      key={1}
      keyboardType='email-address'
      value={this.state.username}
      label='username'
      error={this.state.errorUsername}
/>
```

I have problems with the properties.

**The problem?**

Label **username** is not overriding the default label I've defined in my custom component so the form always displays **test**

**what am I doing wrong?**
The same happens with "error" prop. It's like I can't override properties... What is the best approach for what I wanting to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The props will be overridden by your custom prop, you need to implement some additional login to take into account any props passed down from any Component that uses the InputEditText HOC.

The basic gist is to pull those default props out into an Object, and then [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the override props into that Object and passing down to the TextField.

```
export const InputEditText = (overrideProps) => {
    const props = {
        label: 'test',
        autoCapitalize: 'none',
        fontSize: 20,
        lineWidth: 1,
        titleFontSize: 16,
        labelHeight: 42,
        textColor: 'white',
        tintColor: 'white',
        baseColor: 'rgb(225, 231, 228)',
        autoCorrect: false,
        enablesReturnKeyAutomatically: true,
        onFocus: this.onFocus,
        returnKeyType: 'next',
        ...overrideProps
    };

    return(
        <View style={styles.inputEditText}>
            <TextField {...props} />
        </View>
    );
};
```

Comment: Not working. For each defaulProps I get the following error: ',' expected.  Also using ...overrideProps I get 'Expression expected' error. Did you try the solution? Thanks

Comment: @FaustinoGagneten My mistake, forgot to change the props into an Object properly, can you try my updated answer?

Comment: Still having the same error in ...overrideProps: Expression expected

Comment: Do you know if the spread operator is supported in the transpiler setup you have?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm using Visual Studio Code.  Anyway, running that code I got:"Unexpected token, expected \"}\" in this line:             <TextField {...defaultProps, ...overrideProps} />

Comment: Do you have any news?

Comment: @FaustinoGagneten I've made another change, let me know if it works out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186206/discussion-between-faustino-gagneten-and-dan).